# O que é ">" em CSS3?

Tags: css, css3

Sempre tive esta dúvida: para que serve o `>` no CSS3? Já tentei deduzir em vários arquivos a sua função, mas ainda não entendi.

Isso:

```
nav > li > a { ... }
```

não seria o mesmo que isso?:

```
nav li a{ ... }
```

Comment: Como o @mgibsonbr referiu e a resposta do bacco explica, ele seleciona todos os descendentes imediatos/diretos.